# Python 3 multi-threaded pinger

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multithreading, networking

My goal: I want to ping every single IPv4 address and record whether or not they responded.

The way I have it set up is every IP address corresponds to an index. For example `0.0.0.0` is index `0` and `0.0.1.0` is index `256`. So if `0.0.0.0` responded, then the 0th element of the bitarray is true. At the end I write the bitarray to a file.

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
from bitarray import bitarray
import threading
import time

response_array = bitarray(256 * 256 * 256 * 256)
response_array.setall(False)

def send_all_pings():
    index = 0
    for f1 in range(256):
        for f2 in range(256):
            for f3 in range(256):
                for f4 in range(256):
                    thread = PingerThread(".".join(map(str, [f1, f2, f3, f4])), index)
                    thread.start()
                    index += 1

    time.sleep(30)
    print("Writing response array to file")
    with open('responses.bin', 'wb') as out:
        response_array.tofile(out)


class PingerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, address, index):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.index = index

    def run(self):
        if subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1", "-w", "1", self.address]) == 0:
            response_array[self.index] = True
        else:
            response_array[self.index] = False
```

What can I do to make this run faster? Any optimisations at all, even if very small, are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- IP addresses are only formatted as octets (0-255) for human readability - they actually just represent integers. Instead of for example 127.0.0.1 you can use [2130706433](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/decimalCalcResult?ipAddress=127.0.0.1) (127*2^24+1). In other words, `range(2^32-1)` represents the entire range of IPv4 addresses.
- Using a Python library to ping hosts is very likely going to be much faster than starting a shell command.
- Use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) rather than Python threads to avoid running into the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)
- `response_array` will end up taking many gigabytes of memory. If you really need the kind of detail you're logging you should be writing each entry to disk ASAP (keeping the file open all the while). You could also look into simplifying your reporting, such as only saving the IP addresses which don't respond, or saving to two files, one with responding IPs and the other with non-responding ones. You'll have to store a file (or a pair of files) per process, to avoid them clobbering each other.

Comment: Since this is mostly waiting on a network, async io might be even better than multiprocessing. Although you probably don't want 4 billion open connections, but that's an issue with the original code as well

Comment: Also saving to two files from umpty concurrent processes sounds like either a bottleneck or a way to end up with a file full of garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Opening four billion network connections potentially at once doesn't sound like a good idea. I can't tell right now whether or not you'll hit the OS limit and if it will be handled in some graceful way like blocking until a handle is free, but I'd rather set up a sane limit up front.